# Get overall string text of different dynamic views

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an android fragment that looks something like this:

[image: http://oi41.tinypic.com/5txxcj.jpg]

Every time the user clicks add/remove a new row is added/removed. When they click okay, then I need to return a string for all the views above, for example "TextATextBTextCTextD".

What would be a good way to go about this? I thought about adding tags for each new view, then doing a for loop through each view. But because I have spinners and edit views, I wasn't sure how to get the view for each then get their text.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your tag option isn't bad... everytime you change one of the view's values, you could set the tag of the view to the string value, then iterate over the views and just collect the tags.

Another way to do it, would be to create your own custom spinner / edittext & make them all implement an interface which has a method called `String getDisplayText()`

Then, whenever you create a view, place it in an array of that interface type, then iterate over all your objects and call getDisplayText() on all of them.

Hope this helps :)